# Custom control dynamically update text properties

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, custom-controls

I have a custom control based on a button that can contain some text like this:

```cs
public class TextButtonControl : Button
{
    public bool AllCaps
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(AllCapsProperty);
        set => SetValue(AllCapsProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AllCapsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("AllCaps", typeof(bool), typeof(TextButtonControl), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public string Text
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(TextButtonControl), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    static TextButtonControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextButtonControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TextButtonControl)));
    }
}
```

```xml
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TextButtonControl}">
    <Border Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2">
        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                   FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                   FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   TextAlignment="Center"/>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

How can I make my control's text change from uppercase to lowercase (and vice versa) on the fly when the dependency property `AllCaps` is updated?

Example usage:

```xml
<!-- inside some window or user control -->
<ToggleButton x:Name="tbCaseToggle" />
<custom:TextButtonControl Text="some text" Capitalised="{Binding ElementName=tbCaseToggle, Path=IsChecked}" />
```

To change the capitalisation of the button's content as the toggle button gets checked or unchecked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Multi-value Converter

You can create a multi-converter for that, which takes a boolean to indicate capitalization and the text.

```
public class CapitalizationConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      var capitalize = (bool)values[0];
      var text = (string)values[1];

      // Change the capitalization here as you need
      return capitalize ? text.ToUpper() : text.ToLower();
   }

   public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new InvalidOperationException();
   }
}
```

Create an instance of the converter in a resource dictionary that your control template can access.

```
<local:CapitalizationConverter x:Key="CapitalizationConverter"/>
```

Then use a multi-binding in your control template that binds the `AllCaps` and the `Text` property and uses the converter to capitalize the text depending on the value of `AllCaps`.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TextButtonControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type local:TextButtonControl}">
   <Border Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2">
      <TextBlock FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                 FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 TextAlignment="Center">
         <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CapitalizationConverter}">
               <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="AllCaps"/>
               <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Text"/>
            </MultiBinding>
         </TextBlock.Text>
      </TextBlock>
   </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

### Exposing Another Property

Another way is to expose a read-only dependency property `DisplayText`.

```
private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey DisplayTextPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(
   nameof(DisplayText), typeof(string), typeof(TextButtonControl),
   new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(string), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None));

public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayTextProperty = DisplayTextPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

public string DisplayText
{
   get => (string)GetValue(DisplayTextProperty);
   private set => SetValue(DisplayTextPropertyKey, value);
}
```

When the `AllCaps` or `Text` properties change reformat the `DisplayText` property. This is an example for `AllCaps` only, but it works the same way for `Text`, too.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty AllCapsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
   "AllCaps", typeof(bool), typeof(TextButtonControl), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnAllCapsChanged));

private static void OnAllCapsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   var textButtonControl = (TextButtonControl)d;
   textButtonControl.DisplayText = textButtonControl.FormatText();
}

private string FormatText()
{
   return AllCaps ? Text.ToUpper() : Text.ToLower();
}
```

In your control template, you would just bind to `DisplayText`.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
           FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
           FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           TextAlignment="Center"/>
```

Comment: I'll give that a shot!

Comment: You're a bloody lifesaver, I'd first tried a normal binding but I couldn't get around binding to template binding!